# See logs when AndroidStudio is stuck on Gradle: Build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

How to understand what and why really happens behind `Gradle: Build`? There is no console or crashes, just endless building. Maybe there is network issue which happens again and again, but how can developer know it?

This is a sample of just new project:
[image]

From terminal everything works fine. So the question is not about how to solve particular problem, but more about generic solution when IDE doesn't show anything except "progress".

Answer (score 1):

You can execute `./gradlew build` manually in the terminal to see its logs. You can also add `--debug` or `--stacktrace`parameter to enable verbose logging.

Comment: The problem is not in terminal. The problem is in understanding why AndroidStudio doesn't start.

Comment: i know, but if it is stuck in Gradle, you can start the gradle build separately (Android Studio does the same). But in terminal you will actually see what is going on (it will be the same log output that Android Studio is hiding from you in this moment).
This way you can analyze things that Android Studio is doing in background if you open a new project.

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar answer to Andre, but with a suggestion of some potential culprits.

If an issue is happening, Android Studio is just a GUI wrapper on the terminal. So just run the commands and see what the hold up or error is.

However, Often times when I see freezing up that takes a long time to fail it is network related items. Such as an internal Maven repo that is not resolving properly. So check your internal Maven repos as well that they exist and you set them up correctly.

You can also turn off the internet and start it up, it will load into offline mode and not attempt to load any internet items and offers popup to move to offline mode in gradle. This will give you a chance to make your corrections until Android Studio improves these issues.

Comment: Why the downvote? I gave a valid suggestion and solution to try getting into Android Studio and a potential culprit. I'm confused at who would downvote a valid suggestion..

Answer (score -2):

Rather than Choosing Start a New Android Project, Open an Existing Project and then

```
goto file>>new >>new Project
```

If You create android project by following these steps , You can see every error of you gradle build in

```
logcat
```

[image: gradle]

Comment: this is unfortunately wrong since logcat is showing you the log on your android device and not build/studio related output